# Some Properties are not mapping with json using NewtonJson

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am using a **shopifySharp** library Order entity to map Shopify orders with the class object. The problem is that some properties are mapping fine but some are not.

I am not getting why this behavior is happening.

```
public class Order
{
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("admin_graphql_api_id")]
        public string AdminGraphQLAPIId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("app_id")]
        public long? AppId { get; set; }
}
```

The complete object is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp/blob/master/ShopifySharp/Entities/Order.cs).

And my **JSON** object looks like the one below. I removed some of the properties otherwise its gets too long to post here:

```
{
    "id": 4538882687054,
    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Order/4538882687054",
    "app_id": 1354745
}
```

And Controller code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class OrderController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("Order")]
  public IActionResult Order(Order order)
  {
    return Ok(order);
  }
}
```

I also attached screenshots.

[image: Only showing Id value]

[image: Post response]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API is probably using `System.Text.Json` serializer. There is nothing wrong with your object, but it will only work correctly with `Newtonsoft`.

In order to make your API use `Newtonsoft` you need to configure it in `Startup`:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Edit:

If you are not bound to any specific `Newtonsoft` feature, you can also just use the official json serializer from Microsoft: `System.Text.Json`, which is more performant, but for that you need to add to your object the attribute `[JsonPropertyName("your_prop")]`.